# Cant local debug Azure Function CLI Update March 7th 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Im using VS 2015. I went to locally debug my function and a new Azure Function CLI was downloaded on build. Now all my azure funtion project have this error for each function.

"Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Frameworks, Version=3.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

What steps do I need to take to fix this or is there a way to roll back the CLI to a previous version?

Comment: Is your NuGet  fully up to date?

Comment: Yeah. downloaded the newest version and also ran the package command line to update nuget

Comment: Also reported on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d599889a-8ec7-4213-9b21-2544d6a18f51/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: Thank you! Keep my eye out there also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: A new version was published on NPM 36 minutes ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-cli

VS should prompt you to download and install version 93 now.

---

This was reported in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/81.

There's a problem with the latest version, it doesn't include some dll files.

To fix it you can copy the files yourself from the previous version's folder in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0-beta.91` to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0-beta.92`.

Files to copy:

- NuGet.Frameworks.dll
- NuGet.LibraryModel.dll
- NuGet.Versioning.dll

Comment: this should be fixed in 1.0.0-beta.93

Comment: Thank You! Worked!